# Deprecated API calls blocking update to GKE 1.22 - [Update]

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to upgrade some GKE cluster from 1.21 to 1.22 and I'm getting some warnings about deprecated APIs. Am running Istio 1.12.1 version as well in my cluster

One of them is causing me some concerns:

`/apis/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses`

I was surprised to see this warning because we are up to date with our deployments. We don't use Ingresses.

Further deep diving, I got the below details:

```
➜ kubectl get --raw /apis/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses | jq
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
{
  "kind": "IngressList",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "191638911"
  },
  "items": []
}
```

It seems an IngressList is that calls the old API. Tried deleting the same,

```
➜  kubectl delete --raw /apis/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses
Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): the server does not allow this method on the requested resource
```

Neither able to delete it, nor able to upgrade.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

[Update]: My GKE cluster got updated to `1.21.11-gke.1900` and after that the warning messages are gone.

Answer (score 4):

we have also upgraded cluster/Node version from 1.21 to 1.22 directly from GCP which have successfully upgraded both node as well as cluster version.

even after upgrading we are still getting ingresslist

```
/apis/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses
```

we are going to upgrade our cluster version from 1.22 to 1.23 tomorrow will update you soon.

Comment: Thank @bipin joshi . Please let me know. My current version is `1.21.11-gke.900`. Did you directly upgrade to the next minor  version 1.22, skipping other 1.21.xx version?

Comment: Hi @Sunil yes i have directly upgraded from 1.21 to 1.22, after that GKE asked me to upgrade node version i have upgraded node version from 1.21 to 1.22 as well.

Comment: Around 2 hrs ago i have upgraded cluster/node version from 1.22 to 1.23.5-gke.1501.  

I have checked every thing all CI/CD pipelines , re build them every thing is working fine. 

i suggest you can take downtime and proceed with upgrade node upgrade genrally takes ( 5*number of nodes ) minutes to upgrade.

Thanks

Comment: Cool, I shall do it in DEV and check. 
After changing to 1.23.5, Is the error gone? 
Also, do you use Istio as Service Mesh ?

Comment: Hi @Sunil the notification error `migrate to updated APIs` is still there, we are looking into that, Although `kubectl get --raw /apis/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses | jq` returns  _Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource_ .

And no we are not using Istio.
Thanks

Comment: we have also checked `kubectl get --raw /apis/networking.k8s.io/v1/ingresses | jq` and  this display `{
  "kind": "IngressList",
  "apiVersion": "networking.k8s.io/v1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "********"
  },
`
seems like error will get remove  from GCP in 24 hrs..

Comment: For your GKE upgrade,
Are you on Static version ( manually upgradation ) or on Release Channel ( Let GKE automatically manage the cluster's control plane version. ) ? @bipin joshi

Comment: Our GKE upgrade is in Static channel.

Comment: We are also on static channel. I shall try to upgrade by today or tomorrow and let know.

Comment: I have updated to 1.22 today. The message `migrate to updated APIs` still there. Will wait for 2 days and see

Comment: Hi @Sunil  `migrate to updated APIs`  error is still there. we are in node version 1.23 and that error still shows us the  `This cluster will not be scheduled for an automatic upgrade to v1.22, the next minor version...` . I think there is some issue from google's end, we are going to drop a mail to google regarding the same..
@Sunil do you have google support ??

Comment: Oh OK ! I guess may be some bug from the Google console UI !! Currently we don't have support. But let me try some way to check the same.
If you get some info, please let me know

Comment: It would seem that we need to manually remove the warning message by clicking the "Dismiss" button located on the side panel. The removal warning message is not automatic and must be removed manually. 
I clicked and the message was removed .

Answer (score 4):

In our case, use of old version of [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) seems to cause the beta version of API calls. Some days after updating kube-state-metrics, the deprecated API calls was stopped so far.

Comment: The same for us. It actually ended up being the datadog helm chart installing a 2 year old version of kube-state-metrics. Migration to kubeStateMetricsCore solved it for us

Comment: In my case, we don't have kube-state-metrics