# Deprecated API calls blocking the update to GKE 1.22

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

[Note: this is a very similar issue to [Deprecated API calls blocking update to GKE 1.22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72654617/deprecated-api-calls-blocking-update-to-gke-1-22-update) but with different resources and I could not find any relevant answers in the question above nor elsewhere]

Current versions: the control plane and the worker nodes 1.21.14-gke.2700.

I have checked through the official documentation from both [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22) and the [official Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#v1-22).

For the rest of the applications that are calling the deprecated APIs (Ingress, `validatingwebhookconfigurations`, etc), I've cleaned them up, upgraded them, etc.
This is the last one.

[image]

I've tried to find what is [SubjectAccessReviews](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/) on the cluster and seems like GKE doesn't allow calling the APIs

```
~ kubectl get subjectaccessreviews -A
Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): the server does not allow this method on the requested resource
```

```
~ kubectl get --raw '/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/subjectaccessreviews' | jq
Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): the server does not allow this method on the requested resource
```

(I am the cluster admin)

As the User-agent says, this comes from "kube-metrics-adapter" which is a basically Prometheus/Istio-based HPA adapter from this [istio-hpa](https://github.com/stefanprodan/istio-hpa).

I've also tried looking whether there are any resources related to the SubjectAccessReviews but could not find any.

(I've upgraded all the deprecated APIs from `rbac.yaml` and the `custom-metrics-apiservice.yaml` but still see the deprecated APIs call)

I am running out of ideas on how to resolve this so any suggestions would be really helpful.

**Update: 20th Oct 2022**

I've been keeping track of the API calls over the past few days and the number seems to be decreasing. However, something flipped and the numbers are now increasing and I am not sure why.Update: 20th Oct 2022

**Update: 25th Oct 2022**

The numbers are now decreasing again!

```
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.0     11319613    October 12  2022    at  4:02:00     AM  UTC+8   0
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.0     11317741    October 13  2022    at  4:55:00     AM  UTC+8   1872
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.0     11304316    October 14  2022    at  4:33:00     AM  UTC+8   13425
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.0     11299258    October 15  2022    at  4:43:00     AM  UTC+8   5058
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.0     11296307    October 17  2022    at  3:57:00     AM  UTC+7   2951
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.0     11297258    October 18  2022    at  3:28:00     AM  UTC+7   -951
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.0     11298491    October 19  2022    at  3:16:00     AM  UTC+7   -1233
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.0     11283428    October 20  2022    at  3:22:00     AM  UTC+7   15063
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.0     11205735    October 20  2022    at  10:22:00    PM  UTC+8   77693
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.0     10827732    October 21  2022    at  10:22:00    PM  UTC+8   378003
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.1     10589268    October 22  2022    at  8:00:00     AM  UTC+8   238464
kube-metrics-adapter/v0.0.1     10366437    October 23  2022    at  8:13:00     AM  UTC+8   222831
```

I've tried using [kubent](https://github.com/doitintl/kube-no-trouble) like `kubent -l debug` but it can't retrieve the deprecated SubjectAccessReviews apis.

```
10:07PM DBG Retrieving: subjectaccessreviews.v1.authorization.k8s.io                                                                                                                        
10:07PM DBG Failed to retrieve: authorization.k8s.io/v1, Resource=subjectaccessreviews: the server does not allow this method on the requested resource                                     
10:07PM DBG Retrieving: selfsubjectaccessreviews.v1.authorization.k8s.io                                                                                                                    
10:07PM DBG Failed to retrieve: authorization.k8s.io/v1, Resource=selfsubjectaccessreviews: the server does not allow this method on the requested resource                                 
10:07PM DBG Retrieving: localsubjectaccessreviews.v1.authorization.k8s.io                                                                                                                   
10:07PM DBG Failed to retrieve: authorization.k8s.io/v1, Resource=localsubjectaccessreviews: the server could not find the requested resource                                               
10:07PM DBG Retrieving: tokenreviews.v1.authentication.k8s.io                                                                                                                               
10:07PM DBG Failed to retrieve: authentication.k8s.io/v1, Resource=tokenreviews: the server does not allow this method on the requested resource
```

Update: 30 Jan 2023

I've managed to resolve it but it might not be what you guys are looking for nor not work for you. I uninstalled the "istio-hpa" components that were affecting it. After that, the warnings were gone.

Comment: You will see the the deprecation insight warning/recommendation until GKE does not detect usage of the API for 30 days.  So even if you update all deprecated resources, you'll still see the warning and automatic upgrades will be remain paused.

That being said, even though you'll still see the warning, you should see that they number times something has been called stays the same once you've updated all resources.

Comment: @GariSingh Right, I've been monitoring that as well and will do so for a couple more days! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @GariSingh The number of the API seems to decrease (pls see my edit above). Does it mean it's no longer an issue?

Comment: Yeah ,,, if they date last called stays the same and the number of calls decreases, then you should be good!

Comment: @GariSingh Something stranged happened and the API calls seem to be increasing again. Hmmm

Comment: Have u found any solution? I'm facing the same issue..

Comment: Hey @OğuzÇiçek are you also using the same "istio-hpa" or something else?

Comment: API shows: /apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/subjectaccessreviews ,  User agent shows: adapter/v0.0.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/$Format , I'm not sure if we use "istio-hpa" but we have so many clusters and workloads. So, i couldn't change this APIS..

Comment: Right. One thing that I did is to run something like kubent (https://github.com/doitintl/kube-no-trouble) and check the deprecated APIs and try to upgrade as much as we can. However, it doesn't really help with this `SubjectAccessReviews` thing :/

Comment: @YeLinAung If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: @DharaniDharGolladasari I've managed to resolve it but it might not be what you are looking for nor not work for you. I uninstalled the "istio-hpa" components that were affecting it. After that, the warnings were gone.